# SafariViewController not opening with hidden:true in IOS 17.1

Tags: ios, cordova, webkit, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I got the update on IOS 17.1 on my IOS device later tonight and after that my Application is not loading the login page.

I am using SafariViewController for with below option and its not executing the loaded event anymore.

```
SafariViewController.show({
            url: url,
            hidden: true,
            animated: false
        },(result) =>{
            console.log(result);
            if (result.event === 'opened') {
                
                console.log('performLogoutUsingSafariViewController >> opened');
            } else if (result.event === 'loaded') {
                
                console.log('performLogoutUsingSafariViewController >> loaded');
                // Some logic executes here 
            } else if (result.event === 'closed') {
                
                console.log('performLogoutUsingSafariViewController >> closed');
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I am only getting the below console while the url loads fine "performLogoutUsingSafariViewController >> opened".

Looks like IOS 17.1 blocking the Hidden SafariViewController to load anything now. Below is the message i see from IOS documentation.

> ** Important In accordance with App Store Review Guidelines, when you present this view controller, it must visibly present information to
> users. You may not hide or obscure the view controller behind other
> views or layers. Additionally, you may not use SFSafariViewController
> to track users without their knowledge and consent. **

Any Help ?